# Nginx $server_name in if statement

Tags: variables, if-statement, nginx, server-name

It seems like this is not working:

```
server_name blabla.bla;    
    location ~* (wp-comments-posts|wp-login)\.php$ {
            if ($http_referer !~ ^(http://$servername) ) {
            return 405;
            }
     }
```

While

```
server_name blabla.bla;    
    location ~* (wp-comments-posts|wp-login)\.php$ {
            if ($http_referer !~ ^(http://blabla.bla) ) {
            return 405;
            }
     }
```

works just fine. Is this expected and if so why? Or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regular expressions are compiled while reading configuration, thus they cannot contain variables.

Also please note:

- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_referer_module.html

Comment: Thanks! I know the "if's" are evil, but letting php execute all the brute force password crack attempts is even more evil (performance wise).

Comment: My remark is more about your use of `$http_referer` instead of special `$invalid_referer`.

Comment: *palms face* Thanks! Again!

Comment: @greg if preventing brute force attacks is your objective I suggest you move it to the TCP layer,  using [fail2ban](http://www.fail2ban.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page).

Answer (score 0):

If you have the referer module you might like this one, this will ONLY allow the current server names to be valid referrers. All others will return as 405 error.

```
        location ~* (wp-comments-post)\.php$ {
            valid_referers server_names;
            
            if ( $invalid_referer ) {
                    return 405;
            }

            ### Do your stuff here
              
        }
```